# How to send multiple client using socket.id that are connected to socket (Nodejs, Socket.io)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

```
socket.on('private-message', function(data){
        console.log("Sending: " + data.content + " to " + data.username);
        console.log(clients[data.username].socket.join(', '));
        if (clients[data.username]){    
            io.sockets.connected[clients[data.username].socket].emit("add-message", data);
        } else {
            console.log("User does not exist: " + data.username);
        }
    });
```

This code is working fine but what I want is, I want to send multiple connected clients connected to the socket using their socket id.

**io.sockets.connected[reciver.socketid].emit("add-message", data);**

Is there any way or is it is possible to write the group of receiver socket.id. I don't want to use for loop.

Comment: socket.broadcast.emit('broadcast', 'hello friends!');

Comment: in that broadcast is your "add-message"

Comment: let me know if you have an issue.

Comment: I don't want to just broadcast all. I want to emit only particular or selected clients using their socket.id. Not all..

Comment: then you should loop through or create an specific intended client's array and send the message my friend.

Comment: you mean io.sockets.connected[socketid, socketid2, etc].emit("add-message", data);

Comment: tried this sadly not working

Comment: one more way is to create a namespace of specific group and then you may sent to them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172057/discussion-between-dipak-chavda-and-biswajit).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Feel free to use my Socket.IO Cheatsheet!

```
// Add socket to room
socket.join('some room');

// Remove socket from room
socket.leave('some room');

// Send to current client
socket.emit('message', 'this is a test');

// Send to all clients include sender
io.sockets.emit('message', 'this is a test');

// Send to all clients except sender
socket.broadcast.emit('message', 'this is a test');

// Send to all clients in 'game' room(channel) except sender
socket.broadcast.to('game').emit('message', 'this is a test');

// Send to all clients in 'game' room(channel) include sender
io.sockets.in('game').emit('message', 'this is a test');

// Send to individual socket id
io.sockets.socket(socketId).emit('message', 'this is a test');
```

---

### Update 2021

Here's the [official cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/v4/emit-cheatsheet/) for Socket.IO.

Answer (score 8):

Yes its solved now!! Here we go with answer.

```
io.to(socketid1).to(socketid2).emit("add-message", data);
```

Or you can do this by joining clients to a group. And emit message to that group.

join

```
socket.join(data.username);
```

emit

socket.join(data.username);

*This saved me from writing lot of codes*

Answer (score 0):

You can make subscribe to all user to a room and then you can emit message.

```
socket.join('some room');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I didn't read the docs correct! thanks all!: )

I was looking for this... io.sockets.emit('Test1', response);
  I was using this... socket.emit("Test1", response);

:)